# Connecting to two remote servers at the same time

Tags: c#, sql

I need to connect to two tables on different databases on two sql servers(both are remote) and find any mismatch in the tables. I do not want to compare by looping through the row and columns as the tables are huge. I have tried the sp_addlinkedserver way of linking but i guess i am making some mistake in the syntax. Could anyone provide me the proper syntax? UI am using .NET framework the programming language is C#

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do realize that even if you link the servers together, one of them is going to have to send the entire table to the other to compare them?  When you say "huge" what do you mean?  100,000 rows? 10,000,000 rows?

Comment: @mellamokb - true but it eliminates traffic from one server to app so it should be at least 1/2 quicker than traffic from both servers to app.

Comment: How are you invoking sp_addlinkedserver, why it is failing ? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: @mellamkokb: I figured I'll link both the servers and then query the respective databases using [server].[database].[schema].[table]

Comment: @mellamokb:It's not that huge but the application might encounter tables with that many rows.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar: I made a connection string having the authentication details of the first server and connected to it successfully. Say "conn" is the connection string.           SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_addlinkedserver", conn);
cmd1.CommandType = Data_ref.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server", 'server');
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar: Is it possible to use the connection string having the authentication details of the first server and use it to link the second server?